# when is the Brun continued fraction periodic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, continued-fractions

I was hoping to figure this one out on my own.  There's this nice paper by [Avila](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03692v1) on various "subtractive" Euclidean algorithms.  Here is one he attributes to Viggo Brun:

$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto \text{sort}(x-y, y, z) $$

and I even read [Brun](http://jolivet.org/timo/docs/Brun_algo.pdf)'s original article where he shows a periodic orbit of length 19 for the three numbers:

$$ (\sqrt[3]{4}, \sqrt[3]{2}, 1) \mapsto \big(\sqrt[3]{2} \;,\; 1 \;,\
\sqrt[3]{4}- \sqrt[3]{2} \big)  \mapsto \dots  $$

This one repeats after 19 steps, but actually not. I checked on a computer (and checked my French) after 19 steps the three digits are **proportional** to that in the first step.  So there is periodicity that way.

---

When is this thing periodic?  If it is periodic, there is $3 \times 3$ matrix encoding that sequence and the eigenvalues must be a roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is a cubic.

Conversely, if I get three numbers which are roots to some polynomial
$$ x^3 + ax + b = 0  $$

and if I run the Brun continued fraction with the three roots, $(r_1, r_2, r_3)$ so I always get a periodic sequence?  This makes sense if all three roots $r_1, r_2, r_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ are real numbers.

Alternatively we could try to adjoin $\sqrt[3]{n}$ and get the real cubic extension $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{n})$ and then $1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4}$ span the ring of integer, $\mathcal{O}_K$.  We an ask if this sequence is periodic.

$$ (n^{2/3}, n^{1/3}, 1) \mapsto \big(n^{2/3}- n^{1/3}, n^{1/3}, 1\big ) \mapsto \dots $$

Even in the quadratic case, I don't think I've read carefully the argument that periodic continued fractions **must** be quadratic irrationalities $a + b\sqrt{D}$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.  Perhaps I could read the relevant part of [Khinchin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486696308) or other resource.

---

#### A somewhat precise question

Let $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}P^2$ be three real numbers (up to proportion) and  Brun continued fraction algorithm:

$$ T: (x,y,z) \mapsto \text{sort}(x-y, y, z) $$

what are the closed orbits of this map? I have no idea how to make this precise.  The traditional continued fraction algorithm can also be made subtrative:

$$ T_0: (x,y) \mapsto \text{sort}(x-y, y) $$

and we can record how many times the coordinates get switched in the process - $(12)$ if $x > y$ and $(21)$ if $y > x$ - and this leads to a continued fraction of sorts.  The statement is then:

> Every periodic continued fraction represents a [quadratic irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Continued_fraction_expansion) number and every quadratic irrational number can be represented by a periodic continued fraction.
>
> Khinchin **Continued Fractions** Thm 28 (on p48)

Comment: What is the precise question?

Comment: There may be something useful in Nils Pipping, Verallgemeinerungen des Euklidischen Algorithmus, Acta Acad. Aboensis 18, (1952). no. 5, 17 pp., MR0053896. See also Kops, Selmer's multiplicative algorithm, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4266.pdf